# Very high memory usage when writing xlsx files with axlsx gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, xlsx

I'm using https://github.com/randym/axlsx for writing data to xlsx files. I have problem with memory usage when writing big xlsx files. Here is the code that reproduces problem:

```
Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Test") do |sheet|
    41_000.times do
        sheet.add_row ["test data"] * 600
    end
  end
end
```

This takes around 6gb of ram... Is there any way to do it more efficient? Or maybe there is other library that will do it efficient?

Comment: So you are creating 25 million cells, which translates to 25 million objects (much more than this in reality) maintained in memory, and you complain about performance? You should consider using CSV instead.

Comment: In my real xlsx files are much lighter but still takes around 2gb of server ram. Is there any way to stream this writing to xlsx files?

Comment: XLS internal structure does not allow for stream writing. The whole sheet needs to be loaded in memory. However, you should be able to write some macros which does a vlookup in a csv file and populates the sheet. You can also look into ways of embedding a data source inside the xlsx. These approaches are quite advanced though. They require strong knowledge of Office internals.

Comment: Why not to write CSV instead? The library seams more mature too http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: There's lots of reasons to write to an xlsx file instead of csv, for example formatting, and also not having to tell your users how to import a csv into Excel.  (there's lots can go wrong with this, sometimes silently).

Comment: I agree with Mihai that you can't reasonable expect to build a 25 million cell xlsx file without using large amounts of RAM.  Is the large memory usage actually a problem?  If you are on a shared server you'd run the risk of the process being automatically killed.

Comment: Actually you can. If you were using PHP, I'd recommend you to use [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout). It streams data and only keep one row at a time in memory (so yes, streaming is possible!). I don't know any similar library in Ruby though :(

Comment: RAM Issues with CSV files is a known issue for XLSX files with that gem, and I haven't had much luck with efficently loading XLSX files. I had one client that absolutely required that we fully automate the task and we would only get XLSX files. I ended up using `convert.io` to convert them to CSV files, then importing the data. You may want to consider creating multiple smaller files zipped into a folder instead of one big one. Could also trying using google sheet(s), or look into using a PHP libary. Sadly Ruby ecosystem for this is a bit weak.